# Mobile browser crashes when loading page

Tags: ios, mobile, browser

Recently we found problems that sometimes our webpage crashes on iOS. Its happening both in Chrome and Safari. Has anyone idea how to debug it, or why its happens ?

Its hard to reproduce (actually on some phone we were not able to). So we are trying turning off some components from the page. The page contains lot of HTML (20-100 pages) and some bit heavy javascript components, such as maps, street view or even graphs.

Thanks for any idea or hint. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the webpage, when it is loading on your mobile browser(Safari).

**Follow the below steps:**
Connect your iOS device to MAC--> open Safari on MAC --> In the menu bar you can see Develop option --> On selecting the develop option it will show all the connected devices--> keep the menu popup open and browse your webpage on the connected iOS device.

**Note :** If your device doesn't show up in the develop option please enable it in iOS device settings --> Safari --> advanced --> Web Inspector.